# Sitecore logs not updating until I force an app pool restart

Tags: logging

I've got this strange behaviour happening where my Sitecore log files are not being updated at all unless I restart the app pool, then it seems to flush all the stuff that's been going on into the logs.

I've seen this happening at a couple of clients where I've been working, and I've never had the time to investigate it and sort it out.

The server it's currently happening on is running Sitecore 9.0.2.

Has anyone else seen this happening?  Got a fix?

Comment: I've not had this particular problem, but I've had an issue where two instances of the same Sitecore installation were running at the same time and one locked the log files before its process died. I didn't see any queue of log entries flushed to the log when it released the lock though. This was on 8.2. So perhaps investigate if the file is locked.

Comment: Some of the discussion on this question may be of use https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13705/why-would-i-see-a-double-log-file-or-be-missing-a-log-file